# How to change text for icon in Smart Table SAPUI5

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm trying to convert Status values 0,1 in Smart Table to icons with formatter. So far I created Custom column and populated it with OData and inserted into Smart Table.

Here is my code in XML view for Custom column:

```
</Column>
</columns>
<items>
<ColumnListItem>
 <cells>
  <ObjectStatus 
 text="{Status}" state="{path: 'Status', formatter: '.status'}" />
 </cells>
</ColumnListItem>
</items>
</Table>
```

And this is my controller:

```
status : function(Status){
    if (Status === "0" ){return new sap.ui.core.IconPool.getIconURI("sap-icon://accept");
    }
    else {return new sap.ui.core.IconPool.getIconURI("sap-icon://decline");
    }
   },
```

And I got this error in chrome debugger [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cN5b.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icons are supposed to be passed to the `ObjectStatus` control using property `icon`, not `state`. The `state` property should contain a string/text value which will be used as a textual label.

The formatter could also be much simpler. Instead of passing URI's, you can pass the icon urls as strings:

```
status: function(Status) {
    if (Status === "0") {
        return "sap-icon://accept";
    } else {
        return "sap-icon://decline";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @jpenninkhof. You were right, I found solution and posted it here.

Answer (score 1):

This is solution to change your status value 0,1,2 in Custom column of Smart Table to sapui5 icons.

View.xml

```
<items>
<ColumnListItem >
<cells>
<ObjectStatus icon="{path: 'Status', formatter: '.status'}" />
</cells>
</ColumnListItem>
</items>
```

And controller.js

```
status: function(Status) {
    if (Status === "0") {
        return "sap-icon://status-error";
    }  
    if(Status === "1"){
        return "sap-icon://status-positive";
    }
    if(Status === "2"){
        return "sap-icon://status-critical";
    }
},
```